# Need Working Example of Nest REST API without using Firebase API

Tags: nest-api

I'm struggling trying to find a working example of writing data to the Nest Thermostat API using plain rest. Attempting to write a C# app and cannot use Firebase. The multiple Curl examples posted so far do not work. I have a valid auth_token and can read data without issues. Finding the correct post url is elusive. Can anyone assist?

Examples like

```
curl -v -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/structures/g-9y-2xkHpBh1MGkVaqXOGJiKOB9MkoW1hhYyQk2vAunCK8a731jbg?auth=<AUTH_TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"away":"away"}'
```

don't change any data.

Answer (score 4):

Two things. First, follow redirects with -L. Second, put directly to the away data location, like

```
curl -v -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/structures/g-9y-2xkHpBh1MGkVaqXOGJiKOB9MkoW1hhYyQk2vAunCK8a731jbg/away?auth=<AUTH_TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '"away"'
```

The PUT overwrites all data at a location. The previous command would logically be setting the structure's data to just `{"away":"away"}`.

Comment: It looks like it should work but doesn't do anything. No errors from Curl. The thermostat state does not change. I've tried all sorts of variations on all the writable parameters. Nothing works.

Comment: If the wrong scopes have been chosen you should see a 401. This sounds like a case of not following redirects, which curl doesn't report in non-verbose mode.

Answer (score 2):

user3791884,
Any luck with your C# PUT? Here is C# code that works:

```
    using System.Net.Http;

private async void changeAway()
{
    using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient()) 
    {
        string url = "https://developer-api.nest.com/structures/" + structure.structure_id + "/?auth=" + AccessToken;
        StringContent content = new StringContent("{\"away\":\"home\"}"); // derived from HttpContent
        HttpResponseMessage rep = await http.PutAsync(new Uri(url), content);
        if (null != rep)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("http.PutAsync2=" + rep.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Debug.WriteLine writes this to the Output window:
"http.PutAsync2=StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, private
  Content-Length: 15
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}"

These two methods return a valid structure of my data.

1/ command line
`curl -v -k -L -X GET "https://developer-api.nest.com/structures/Za6hCZpmt4g6mBTaaA96yuY87lzLtsucYjbxW_b_thAuJJ7oUOelKA/?auth=c.om2...AeiE"`

2/ C#

```
private bool getStructureInfo()
{
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        // Create a new HttpWebRequest Object to the devices URL.
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://developer-api.nest.com/structures/?auth=" + AccessToken);
        // Define the request access method.
        myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections=3;
        myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect=true;
        myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        using(HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            if (null != myHttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Store the response.
                Stream sData = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
                // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (sData, Encoding.UTF8);

                Debug.WriteLine("Response Structure stream received.");
                string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.WriteLine(data);
                readStream.Close();
                success = deserializeStructure(data);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("getStructure Exception=" + ex.ToString());
    }
    return success;
}
```