# FirebaseSharp nest-api set thermostat value

Tags: c#, firebase, nest-api

I am trying to set thermostat using FirebaseSharp with no success.
I've downloaded padmore's example from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818265/NET-Works-with-Nest-Guide-to-calling-Nest-API-fro?msg=5010020#xx5010020xx. 
I am getting event when i change the value from the virtual device. I set thermostat to read/write as well.
This is what is do:
The problem is that firebaseClient.Post and firebaseClient.Put are called and never returned. also there is no exception.

```
    private void buttonPost_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        string data = "30";
        string fullPath = "//devices//thermostats//<device id>//target_temperature_high_c";;

        string t;            
        try
        {
            t = firebaseClient.Post( fullPath, data );
            string i = string.Format( "firebaseClient.Post: {0}", t );
            OutMessage( i );
            return;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string i = string.Format( "firebaseClient.Post: exception {0}", ex.Message );
            OutMessage( i );
        }

        try
        {
            t = firebaseClient.Put( fullPath, data );
            string i = string.Format( "firebaseClient.Put: {0}", t );
            OutMessage( i );
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string i = string.Format( "firebaseClient.Put: exception {0}", ex.Message );
            OutMessage( i );
        }
    }
```

So what am I doing wrong?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know anything about FirebaseSharp, but this seems not like a valid path: //devices//thermostats//<device id>//target_temperature_high_c. Did you forget to replace <device id> with your actual ID?

Comment: <device id> - i wrote this instead of my actual device ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just got it.

Using following sample: [Need Working Example of Nest REST API without using Firebase API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499826/need-working-example-of-nest-rest-api-without-using-firebase-api).

```
    private async void changeAway( string structureid, string thermostateId)
    {
        using(HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url =   "https://developer-api.nest.com/";
            StringContent content = null;

            if((string)comboBoxDataType.SelectedValue == "Structures")
            {
                string away = comboBoxDataAway.SelectedValue.ToString();
                url += "structures/" + structureid + "/?auth=" + _accessToken;
                content = new StringContent( "{\"away\":\"" + away + "\"}" );
            }
            else
            {
                if(textBoxPostData.Text == string.Empty )
                {
                    OutMessage( "data can not be empty" );
                    return;
                }

                int data = 0;
                if(int.TryParse( textBoxPostData.Text, out data ) == false)
                {
                    OutMessage( "data must be number" );
                    return;                    
                }

                url += "devices/thermostats/" + thermostateId + "/?auth=" + _accessToken;
                content = new StringContent( "{\"target_temperature_high_c\":" + textBoxPostData.Text + "}" );
            }

            HttpResponseMessage rep = await http.PutAsync( new Uri( url ), content );
            if(null != rep)
            {
                OutMessage( "http.PutAsync2=" + rep.ToString() );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great to hear that you figured it out? Any idea what you were doing wrong in your original code?

Comment: Hi Frank, I used Http put instead of FirebaseSharp.